# Cloned a site but can't log in - redirecting to old site

Tags: wp-admin, migration, clone-site

I've cloned the production site at example.com to my own dev server, calling it example.mydomain.com. It displays OK, as long as I use port 8080 (bypassing my varnish server).

I can successfully log in to the `wp-admin` page at **example.com**, but I can't reach the page at **example.mydomain.com/wp-admin** - it redirects to the homepage of **example.com**.

Suspecting my varnish set up might be at fault, I visited **example.mydomain.com:8080/wp-admin** and was presented with a login form.

However, entering the credentials there logs me into and redirects me to, **example.com/wp-admin/** - the production site. 
I've even looked at the query string that appears thus: **http://example.myserver.com:8080/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.myserver.com%3A8080%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1** - which looks like it'll do the right thing, but no joy.

I've done a full text search of the codebase, looking for places where the server name might be hard coded, and found nothing obvious (except some image links in the CSS).

So I'm thinking maybe there's some config settings stored in the database. But I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Please have a look at this: [Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `wp-config.php` file.

Find these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, and make sure "example.com" is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Also on the database, check for table `wp_options`, check these two **option_name**; `siteurl` and `home`.

Comment: I have same problem with OP. My `wp-config.php` does not contain these two lines. Haven't checked the db yet.

Comment: Add a new question, your problem is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change the url under wp_options on the database: https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-change-wordpress-urls-in-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin